# Alfresco Share site's dashlet for document library

Tags: repository, share, alfresco, sites

I was wondering whether exists any dashlet which allows you to explore a site's document library. As far as I know doesn't exist such dashlet out of the box, there only exists the "Site Content" dashlet but it is slightly limited.

I have been searching around and "googling" and I found these useful resources that could be useful as a starting point if I had to create my own:

http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/05/08/1592

http://code.google.com/p/fme-alfresco-extensions/wiki/GalleryPlusDashlet2

Do somebody know more dashlets/resources targeting this issue? Any suggestion?

As a temporary solution, I'm also thinking in the possibility of taking advantage of the "Web View" dashlet, by configuring in it such URL that retrieves the ***documentlist*** region/component in the ***documentlibrary*** page. For example:, **share/page/components/documentlibrary/documentlist** or **share/page/site/{site}/documentlibrary?region=documentlist**. Maybe it is crazy or what I'm saying doesn't make any sense, but it is just an idea.

Another idea that have just came to my mind is the option of creating a custom Surf/Share page which includes the component/webscript that implements the explorer of the document library, specifically the documentlist component. Then configure the "Web View" dashlet giving the URL that points to the custom page created. Would it make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've done exactly the same, it was not really needed for a Dashlet but for to embed the documentlibrary of a site in an iframe for another site.

So what I did was indeed create a new page template embedded-documentlibrary.

I've copied first the following files and renamed them:

1. site-data/pages/documentlibrary.xml
2. site-data/template-instances/documentlibrary.xml
3. site-webscripts/org/alfresco/documentlibrary.ftl

If you rename file 3 or put it in another folder, you need to check the paths in file 1 & 2.

So to make only the documentlibrary appear instead of everyting I just removed everything in file 3 within the `<div id="alf-hd">` tag.

If you remove the tag, the document-tree will also be removed and it gave some javascript errors. This should be fixed in the latest version, but haven't tied that.

So it's extremely easy to create your own page and instead of navigating to site/documentlibrary you just navigate to site/embedded-documentlibrary or your own name you've chosen.

And yes then you'll need to use the web-view Dashlet to show it.

The only thing you need to know is, that the links open within the iframe. So if you use the web-view Dashlet, you need to open the links in a new window.
For my situation I needed an iframe, in your case you could also just let the freemarker from your Dashlet render the components needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I did yesterday just after posting my question. I followed exactly the same process that you have described and it worked! ([This is the result](http://postimage.org/image/cfstf3v9t/)). Actually I didn't had any JS error after removing the header (`<div id="alf-hd">`) and the footer (`<div id="alf-ft">`), I experienced some problems when I tried to remove the left pane components (`<div class="yui-b" id="alf-filters">`). Is it what you tried to mean? Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Yeah I didn't mean the header, but the left treeview pane. So instead of removing the left pane, I just removed some filters like my documents etc.

Comment: Great. Well now I'm wondering how to remove some functionality from the resultant "embedded-documentlibrary", for example, it is not needed the "Create content" button as well as the "Create folder" button. I would like to avoid direct modification of original components code, so I have in mind for example take advantage of the new Alfresco 4's customization feature called "Advanced Component configuration" aka module extensions. What do you think? Is it possible and feasible? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, take a look at this: https://devcon.alfresco.com/cmis/views/workspace%253A%252F%252FSpacesStore%252Fa6424035-cc3e-48eb-a0c5-944274d58bd7 so after 4.0 you can use this technique which is quite powerfull

Comment: Quite useful presentation Tahir. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to see a couple of site visualization and navigation dashlets on Alfresco Visualization Tools available on https://github.com/bhagyas/alfresco-visualization-tools. The project is still at it's initial phase, but you will find interesting snippets of code used to retrieve the document library content trees within the dashlets.

The project was presented by me at Alfresco DevCon in Berlin just a week ago to bring interactive navigation and content analytics. If interested, you can find the slides at the lightening talk slides in the DevCon 2012 site at Alfresco.

Cheers! =)

Comment: Interesting initiative bhagyas. I'm currently checking it and it seems only can be deployed as AMP, isn't it? Well I'm trying to find the slides but I cannot find it, can you post a link please?

Comment: Sure, you can find it under the slides - starting from 168. http://devcon.alfresco.com/berlin/sessions/lightning-talks-session-2

Comment: Thanks, it is very interesting and awesome. I will consider your initiative as a possible module for my project in the future, honestly in this stage it would be "too much". Nevertheless it is worth to spend some time reading and understanding the code, I'm sure I will find very interesting stuff and ideas. Thank you very much for your help and congratulations for such ambitious project!

Answer (score 0):

There is a document-liberary-display dashlet available in the alfresco add-on list which can be used to show all the documents from document-library on site-dashlet.
http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/document-library-display-dashlet