# How to automatically add parameter on every HTTP request?

Tags: java, javascript, http, share, alfresco

For some specific reasons, I would need to automatically add or append a parameter to URL on every request if and only if that parameter already exists in URL since the first request. In other words, if I have the URL `/share/page/site/sample/documentlibrary?embedded`, every request to `/share/page/site/sample/[whatever]` must contain the embedded parameter plus other parameters that could be added by the original request.

I'm working with Alfresco Share (v4.2.b) what means that the web application already exists and despite of I can perform customization, I have limitations because I don't have full control on it. If it was my web app created from scratch it wouldn't be a problem. According to the restrictions I have, the solution ideally should be as less intrusive as possible. At the same time if it is a JavaScript based solution, the use YUI rather than other library is a plus but not a requirement.

I have been searching looking for an approach and after that I have in mind the next possible solutions:

1. Using JavaScript by adding the parameter to URL before every page unload. Something like:

   ```
       window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
           // Add parameter to target URL
           };
   ```

   But I believe it doesn't work as I was reading and according to some tests I did. It seems there is a sort of security restriction (which makes sense by the way).
2. By updating the `href` attribute of every link (`<a/>`) using JavaScript too, once the page has finished loading. For example, `/share/page/site/sample/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/089acea3-3b37-403d-9a8d-ae484ddd2ccb` could be transformed to `/share/page/site/sample/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/089acea3-3b37-403d-9a8d-ae484ddd2ccb&embedded`. The problem of this solution is that both forms GET or POST and href triggered using JavaScript would be out of scope...
3. Using any URL rewrite technique or library like [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (didn't have time yet to test it, sorry).
4. Create an Alfresco Share [extension module](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/Surf_v4_components_Share.html) which changes or updates every request, maybe with the help of a module or subcomponent evaluator. I don't know if it is doable with extension modules, but I believe I read anywhere that you can perform changes to requests.

I have to add (for those with Alfresco Share knowledge) that options 1, 2 and 4 would be implemented as an extension module.

Well, I hope I have explained good enough my question. I'd strongly appreciate some advice or possible approaches. I will keep working on it anyway and I will come up with any update.

Answer (score 2):

1. If it's for every request then a filter is the best. Share already uses the urlrewrite like you've stated so change the default one and add your parameter to it.
2. If you have knowledge of share then overriding the included template would be nice:
   override `alfresco-template.ftl` which is in templates/org/alfresco/include. This template is always loaded when generating a page. It also has the portletMode defined for the Liferay Portlet.
3. What we've done to embed the documentlibrary is to define our own
   share custom page, so I didn't need the 'always' present arg any
   more.

Comment: I've never used UrlRewrite explicitly, do you know roughly what would be required to add in `urlrewrite.xml`? Regarding your second option, I have some knowledge on Share but I don't understand what you suggest to do. Regarding the third option, I did the same for embedded documentlibrary (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13376026/1514315), but I'm trying to go  slightly further for several reasons which are out of scope here (if you want I can share it with you and discuss, probably you are interested). Thanks.

Comment: if you see the urlrewrite it just kinda proxy it, so you could add your static param after it. If you want more control, then just add another own Java filter in the web.xml and write your Java code to add your param or attribute to the request. For option 2 & 3 you need to provide extra info, normally you need the param to check on it somewhere in your share code, so basically with 2 & 3 you don't need to have a param, you can just use a JS global initialisation.

Comment: Actually I had my embedded documentlibrary working before asking this question, the problem is that if you access to document-details the embedded mode is lost because the parameter I'm using to signal it is not available anymore. Basically what I need is to find out a way to keep signaling the embedded mode, as the out-of-the-box portlet extension does. By the way, I'm using an extension module which hides specific regions if the parameter is present using a custom evaluator.

Answer (score 1):

What about proxying connections via Apache HTTPd using `mod_proxy` and then using `mod_rewrite` to redirect user requests if they do not already contain the mandatory parameter? Using the `RewriteRule` directive you can specify quite rich expressions that would add the parameter if it is not already there ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

Comment: That sounds promising, but I have used Apache HTTPd so it is something that I have to investigate. I'm going to strongly consider your proposal, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Alfresco but, one other option would be to have a custom JSP tag.

Lets call it customlink then when you render a link on the page use this custom jsp tag instead of an `<a>` tag.

E.g

```
<mynamespace:customlink href="/somelink">My Content</mynamespace:customlink>
```

The custom JSP tag can then be responsible for checking the query string parameter on the request and if it exists then appends it to the URL and prints the  tag with the query string.

This has the benefit of not depending on JS or exposing any of this to the client side. It also allows further expansion in future.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to do. I cannot do such thing in Alfresco Share. Share is a web app that already exists, and you can customize it creating extension modules which, roughly, can prevent sections rendering, replace sections, add custom content before or after sections and not too much. I understand it is difficult to figure out the restrictions I have if you have never worked with Alfresco Share.